# Salesforce Lightning Design System minified css file inconsistent between managed and unmanaged packages

Tags: visualforce-component, css, lightning-design-system, slds

I am using the minified 2.1.3 version of the SLDS css file in a package I am working on. I am noticing inconsistencies, mainly with the calc() function, in the css file between my dev org and when I create a managed package. Here is one example, the Process bar:

If you notice below, the arrows between the steps are properly rendered, with the CSS as follows:
`.slds-tabs--path__item:before{content:'';display:block;position:absolute;top:2px;left:-1rem;width:calc(2rem - (2px * 2));height:calc(2rem - (2px * 2));`

Notice the spacing between the items in the calc() function.

[image]

This is when I create a managed package from my code. Notice the arrows are not rendered here, and the css for this is as follows:
`.slds-tabs--path__item:before{content:'';display:block;position:absolute;top:2px;left:-1rem;width:calc(2rem -(2px * 2));height:calc(2rem -(2px * 2));`

Notice that the spacing in the calc() function is now different, the minus sign and the parenthetical expression no longer have a space between them.

[image]

Has anyone encountered inconsistencies like these before?

Comment: I think this might be related to the question I just asked; http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146304/did-salesforce-recently-update-their-aura-library-facing-weird-issues-with-acce

Comment: I'm not sure. I am not using the CSS inside a Lightning component.